# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host - Self-hosted Nancy app on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nancy

I have the following code in my Program.cs to start a self-hosted nancy app on Mono 4.2.2.

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {           
        var uri = "";

        if(ReflectConfiguration.CurrentEnviroment == ReflectConfiguration.Environments.Production || ReflectConfiguration.CurrentEnviroment == ReflectConfiguration.Environments.Staging)
        {
            uri = string.Format("http://localhost:{0}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT").ToString());
        }
        else if(ReflectConfiguration.CurrentEnviroment == ReflectConfiguration.Environments.Development)
        {
            uri = string.Format("http://localhost:8888");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Reflect.Web application on " + uri);

        // initialize an instance of NancyHost
        var host = new NancyHost(new Uri(uri));
        host.Start();  // start hosting

        // check if we're running on mono
        if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
        {
            // on mono, processes will usually run as daemons - this allows you to listen
            // for termination signals (ctrl+c, shutdown, etc) and finalize correctly
            UnixSignal.WaitAny(new[] {
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGQUIT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGHUP)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        host.Stop();  // stop hosting
    }
```

This code ran fine for months. Just now this error started showing up:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host '+'
```

on this line:

```
host.Start();  // start hosting
```

I am not aware of any updates I have made recently to any dependency.

Has anyone ever come across this before? And why the '+' sign?

Answer (score 0):

`+` can be part of the "URI prefix string" that .NET's HttpListener (not sure about mono) uses to determine where it should host the application, check out the [HttpListener's Class remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) for more information:

> Similarly, to specify that the HttpListener accepts all requests sent to a port, replace the host element with the "+" character, "https://+:8080". The "*" and "+" characters can be present in prefixes that include paths.

My guess is that your code is checking `ReflectConfiguration.CurrentEnviroment` and missing the cases you're selecting for.

Is there not an environment configured/present? or are you not in Production, Staging, or Development? What is the value of `uri` when you create a new `URI` object?

Comment: Thank you. There was an issue with my hostfile though that did created the error.